# What is the definition of the characteristic function in this proof from Real & Complex Analysis by Walter Rudin?

Tags: real-analysis

The theorem is:
$$\text{Let } f:X\to [0,\infty] \text{ be measurable}.$$
$$\exists \text{ simple measurable functions } s_n \text{ on } X \text{ such that }:$$

> (a) $0\le s_i \le f$ $i\in \mathbb{N}$

> (b) $s_n(x)\to f(x)$ as $n\to \infty$ $\forall x\in X$

Condition (b) is more like:
$$ \lim_{n\to \infty\\ \forall x\in X}s_n(x)=f(x).$$

Condition (a) expands:
$$ 0\le s_1 \le s_2 \le \cdots \le f.$$

I am stuck because I do not know how to do a proper epsilon-delta proof.
My attempt is something along the lines of arguing that  approximate  from below and lead up to a boundary line where  is "ahead" of all the other functions in the set. I don't know if this is true because I didn't read the proof in the textbook by Rudin.

---

The proof in the textbook (on p.16 of the second edition) is something like this:

For $n$ from 1 to infinity, and for $1\le i\le n2^n$, define the sets (?)
$$E_{n,i}=f^{-1}([(i-1)/2^n))$$
and
$$F_n=f^{-1}([n,\infty])$$

and then put ((???))
$$s_n=\sum_{1\le i \le n2^n} \frac{i-1}{2^n}\chi_{E_{n,i}}+n\chi_{F_n}$$

and then the rest of the proof is self referential to another theorem followed by  more explanation.

— - -

It seems $\chi$ is a characteristic function on a set S when S is the subscript of $\chi$. I guess I need to consult Wikipedia for a definition of characteristic functions and return to this question later.

Comment: This is the simple approximation theorem. Is it really left as an exercise? It's one of the fundamental things a textbook should cover before demonstrating the linearity of Lebesgue integration. I find it very likely a hint, or similar partial proof, can be found in the earlier pages of the chapter

Comment: Start with plotting the function $\phi_n(t)=2^{-n}\lfloor 2^n t\rfloor$, $0\leq  t\leq 1$ for example This approximates the identity function $\phi(t)=t$ by step functions an as $n\rightarrow\infty$, $\phi_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\phi$ uniformly.

Comment: @OliverDíaz My picture involved horizontal line functions beneath a function like $f(t)=\text{max}(s_n)+\sin(t)$. Is that even remotely close?

Comment: I don't know how $\sin$ enters into the equation. If you can approximate the identity by step functions that will tell you how to approximate any positive functions.

Comment: @OliverDíaz Your notation confused me, but I think I understand now. Thank you.

Comment: @user: the notation $\lfloor\;\rfloor$ is standard, and denotes the integer part of the argument, that is, $\lfloor x\rfloor =n$ iff $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $n\leq x<n+1$.

Comment: Contrary to your expansion, condition (a) makes no claim as to the relative sizes of the $s_i$. It only says they are all positive and all less than $f$. But there is nothing indicating that one has to less than another.

Comment: That’s correct, @PaulSinclair. Great catch.

Comment: @FShrike The real issue for me is that I couldn’t find the formal definition of a characteristic function $\chi_S$ in the textbook (yet).

Comment: $\mathbb{1}_E$ (or $\chi_E$) is the function that asking the value $0$ to all points $x$ not in $E$ and $1$ to all points $x$ that belong to $E$.

Comment: Okay, thanks. @OliverDíaz. Can you make that an answer so we can close this question with an answer?

Comment: It is not as great a catch as you might think. In fact the sequence $(s_n)_n$ they define has exactly that increasing quality. For some reason, they chose to state the result in a weaker form than they proved. I just pointed out the discrepancy to warn you that you were making an assumption not justified by the information at hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is going on here is the $y$-axis is being partitioned: Consider a finite sequence of increasing $y$ values:
$$0 = y_0 < y_1 < y_2 < \dots < y_m$$
Then you can define the function

$$s(x) = \begin{cases}y_0,&f(x) < y_1\\y_1,&y_1 \le f(x) < y_2\\\vdots\\y_{m-1},& y_{m-1} \le f(x) < y_m\\y_m,&y_m \le f(x)\end{cases}$$

$s$ is a simple function, measurable because $f$ is measurable, and $s \le f$.

Now suppose you have such a sequence for each $n: Y_n = (y_{n,0}, \dots, y_{n,m_n})$. Each of them defines a simple function $s_n \le f$ as above.

Since we want the $s_n$ to converge to $f$, the size of the $y$-axis intervals needs to decrease to $0$ as $n \to \infty$: $\lim_n \max \{y_{n,i} - y_{n,i-1} \mid 1 \le i \le m_n\} = 0$. We also need the top value $y_{m_n}$ to go to $\infty$ for the same reason. If $y_{m_n}$ is bounded and $f$ is not, there will be regions where $f$ is far away from $s_n$ for high $n$.

This is what the explicit sequence $y_{n,i} = \frac i{2^n}, m_n = n2^n$ in their solution accomplishes. The summation of multiples of characteristic functions is just another way of defining the same simple function as I gave above. It is such a common heuristic now that it can be hard for practiced mathematicians to remember how opaque it is when you first encounter it. I'm sure Rudin does give a definition for the characteristic function, but it'll likely be back in the introductory material in the first chapter.

Comment: Thank you so much! Answer accepted!